# How to count instances of a value from another column as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

This is my current df

[image]

my goal is for the "Bad Days" column to count the number of times a unique "device" has a "coverage_count" =< 3.

HissingChubbyDandelion would have '5' for bad days because there are 5 times in the data where coverage_count is less than or equal to 3

I have tried the following line

`df["Bad Days"] = df.groupby("date")["coverage_count" < str(3)].count()`

Comment: Is your `coverage_count` column string type? D:

Comment: when I do df.dtypes it shows "coverage" as type object

Answer (score 1):

You can us `transform` for that.

```
df['bad_days'] = df.groupby('device')['coverage_count'].transform(lambda x: (x <= 3).sum())
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
                     device        date  coverage_count  bad_days
0    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-06               3         5
1    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-07               3         5
2    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-08               2         5
3    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-09               5         5
4    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-10               7         5
5    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-11               3         5
6    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-13               3         5
7        TartToughDandelion  2022-07-06               5         0
8        TartToughDande1ion  2022-07-07               5         0
9        TartToughDandelion  2022-07-08               5         0
10       TartToughDandelion  2022-07-09               5         0
11       TartToughDandelion  2022-07-10               4         0
12       TartToughDande1ion  2022-07-12               5         0
13       TartToughDande1ion  2022-07-13               5         0
14  DemonicDashingDandelion  2022-07-06               7         0
15  DemonicDashingDandelion  2022-07-07               7         0
16  DemonicDashingDandelion  2022-07-08               7         0
17  DemonicDashingDandelion  2022-07-09               7         0
18  DemonicDashingDandelion  2022-07-10               6         0
19  DemonicDashingDandelion  2022-07-12               6         0
20  DemonicDashingDandelion  2022-07-13               6         0
21     BawdySkinnyDandelion  2022-07-06               4         1
22     BawdySkinnyDandelion  2022-07-07               2         1
```

**How this works**

`df.groupby('device')` provides a full sub-frame grouped by `device`.  So the first group it would make available is:

```
                     device        date  coverage_count  
0    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-06               3
1    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-07               3         
2    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-08               2         
3    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-09               5         
4    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-10               7         
5    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-11               3         
6    HissingChubbyDandelion  2022-07-13               3
```

Then a `transform` is done on just the `coverage_count` column of that sub-frame.

```
df['bad_days'] = df.groupby('device')['coverage_count'].transform(...)
```

The transform function - in this case the lambda function - sees the following Series:

```
coverage_count
             3
             3
             2
             5
             7
             3
             3
```

The lambda function - `lambda x: (x <= 3).sum()` - returns a value of 5.  Since `transform` has to return a construct that matches the length of the data provide by the caller, the scalar value of 5 is broadcast to match the length of the sub-frame - in this case a Series containing 7 values of 5.

Comment: which method is iterating across the rows? it is the lambda function?

Comment: I updated the answer to explain how it works.